# Type error when trying to set tzinfo argument for a datetime

Tags: python, class, pyspark, faker, tzinfo

I'm trying to use the faker package to generate fake dates of birth in pyspark.

My code is as below:

```
from faker import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from datetime import *

fake = Faker("en_GB")
fake.seed_locale("en_GB", 0)

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(BIRTH_DT = datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(BIRTH_DT = datetime(2000, 2, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(BIRTH_DT = datetime(2000, 3, 1, 12, 0))
])

class anonymise:
    def BIRTH_DT():
        def BirthDt_values():
            return fake.date_of_birth(datetime.tzinfo == None)
        BirthDt_udf = udf(BirthDt_values, TimestampType())
        return BirthDt_udf()

df = df \
.withColumn("BIRTH_DT", anonymise.BIRTH_DT())

df.display()
```

However I'm getting this error:

> PythonException: 'TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'bool''

I don't understand how it thinks that my parameter value is a boolean?  I must be formatting this incorrectly but I can't figure out what should be done.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Carolina

Comment: `fake.date_of_birth(datetime.tzinfo == None)` change to assignment instead of comparison `fake.date_of_birth(datetime.tzinfo = None)`

Comment: Thanks, if I do that I get a syntax error ```SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  The datatype should be `DateType()` not `TimestampType()` because it's a date of birth and not a timestamp